# how to evaluate this series $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}\cosh(x+n.y) $?

Tags: calculus

How to compute this series ? :

$\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}\cosh (x+n.y)  $    $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~/~~~~x,y \in\mathbb{R}  ~~~~~~~~~~n\in \mathbb{N}$

where $\cosh$ is the hyperbolic cosine .

Comment: I am assuming that the argument is $(x+ky)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\cosh(\theta) = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\theta} +\mathrm{e}^{-\theta}}{2}
$$
so your sum is 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\mathrm{e}^{x+ky} +\mathrm{e}^{-x-ky}}{2}
$$
or
$$
\mathrm{e}^{a+b} = \mathrm{e}^{a}\mathrm{e}^b\\
\mathrm{e}^{ab} =\left(\mathrm{e}^{b}\right)^a 
$$
so we have
$$
\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{e}^x\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\mathrm{e}^{y}\right)^k+\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{e}^{-x}\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\mathrm{e}^{-y}\right)^k 
$$
a sum of the form
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n a^k 
$$
is a geometric one.

Also note:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n a^k = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^n a^k \implies \sum_{k=1}^n a^k  = -1 + \sum_{k=0}^n a^k
$$